# Selinium Code breaks after running ok for some time

Tags: c#, selenium

So I've got a webpage that contains 37 Logos inside the following html code and i need to extract the Text inside the "alt" attribute.

The HTML code is the following :

```
<div class="logo__wrapper col-6 col-sm-4 col-md col-xl -gutter-bottom">
   <div data-lazy="true" data-src="https://www.talkdesk.com/app/themes/talkdesk-com/assets/images/logos/ibm.svg" data-alt="ibm" data-class="logo">
      <img src="https://www.talkdesk.com/app/themes/talkdesk-com/assets/images/logos/ibm.svg" alt="ibm" class="logo" data-load="lazy"></div>
</div>
```

My C# is the following :

```
 IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> customersPresent = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='logo__wrapper col-6 col-sm-4 col-md col-xl -gutter-bottom']"));              
 Assert.Greater(customersPresent.Count, 0);
 string[] customersArray = new string[customersPresent.Count];
 int conta = 0;
 foreach (IWebElement clientes in customersPresent)
 {
   customersArray[conta] = clientes.FindElement(By.TagName("div")).GetAttribute("data-alt");                
   conta++;
   TestContext.Progress.WriteLine("Logos Name Customers Page: " + customersArray[conta]+ "Conta" +conta);
            }
```

The code is running fine but after 31 times the code fails and i got the following message :

```
Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"div"}
```

I'm out of option can you help me , please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think div is not present in the last div

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following approach.

```
 IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> customersPresent = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='logo__wrapper col-6 col-sm-4 col-md col-xl -gutter-bottom']/doc"));
```

Now get the ‘data-alt’ attribute directly for each electing collection